# how to automate word document creation in office 2010

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, client-side, server-side, office-2010

The intranet website is supposed to create a word document client-side from templates
server-side and let the client edit it.
The code that worked in office 2007 doesn't work any more and I can't find any way to do it on google.
I used this code lines which was the only code i did find in google and still nothing

```
         dim appWord
         set appWord = New Word.Application
```

can anyone tell me how to create a word app object that works with word 2010.
thx in advance.

Edit: I need the object to be able to takes parts from various word documents and copy paste them into a single document in a certain formation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the open xml sdk to create and edit office documents, see: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124

Although the download page says office 2007, it works for 2010 as well.

Comment: thx for the answer but i probably cant add this into the server for various reasons if you have any other way to solve it, it'll help

Comment: This sdk just edits the word file as if it were an xml file. There is no need to install office on the server, it is just a dll that is copied in with your application.

Comment: the system is entirely an asp website and i cant add this file to all the computers that will use it

Comment: This code will run on the server. You create a file on the server, give it a temp name and then download it to the client

Comment: the system will generate a temp doc/docx file and then let the user edit the data and save it on the server. will it still work then?

Comment: do you have a comparison table or something on how to convert the vbscript that worked in office word 2007 to one that works on office word 2010? becouse those files only made the word recognize the vbscript object and the only thing that still works are the doc opening, all the copy,paste and bookmarks codes do not work.